# Ruby's awesome_print to STDERR

Tags: ruby, awesomeprint

How to make `ap` function (with its color) outputting to `STDERR`?

```
ap bla # this goes to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Kernel#ai` method to get the awesome_print `String`, then pass it to any output stream you want:

```
STDERR.puts foo.ai
```